# How to resolve region targeting error in Google Actions Console?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a Google Action deployed to production in English to every region supported by the platform supported by the Actions for Families programme. I am trying to update some of the directory information and republish the new version through the environments (alpha, beta, production). I have not changed the region targeting information but I'm getting an error when I submit for alpha.

> only countries may be used for region targeting

It is not clear what this error means or what I need to do to resolve it. The location targeting options include various regions which are not countries but these have historically worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work-around for this problem

1. Disable the 'For Families' option in Directory Information and Save
2. Disable all locations except one in Location Targeting and Save
3. Submit for Alpha
4. Reselect all locations in Location Targeting and Save
5. Reenable the 'For Families' option in Directory Information and Save
6. Submit for Alpha again

This is far from ideal, especially if you support a large number of locations but not all possible locations.